# JSON/Jackson Output is adding unexpectedly a "parent" element on each node

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm using Java 12 / Jacskon 2.9.9 to 'read from' and 'write to' that holds a very simple JSON array within.

I'm reading this into a Map which works perfectly.

The issue is when writing an updated Map I get an outer element that causes some nesting and breaks my code.

**Orignal JSON**

```
 [
        {
            "puid": "sys1",
            "host": "127.0.0.1",
            "syst": "U",
            "user": "xxxx",
            "pass": "secret"
        },
        {
            "puid": "sys2",
            "host": "myhost",
            "syst": "U",
            "user": "yyyy",
            "pass": "secret2"
        },
        {
            "puid": "sys3",
            "host": "localhost",
            "syst": "U",
            "user": "zzzz",
            "pass": "secret3"
        }
    ]
```

I am reading this file into a List<> which works perfectly well. I can use this list to do meaningful things.

The idea is that via an API call I supply a similar JSON element and it re-writes the whole file with the new and existing elements in the format below.

However...
It is writing it like this - with the outer `"sys1"`, `"sys2"`, `"sys3"` elements/nodes.

**Updated JSON**

```
 {
      "sys1" : {
        "puid" : "sys1",
        "host" : "127.0.0.1",
        "syst" : "U",
        "user" : "xxxx",
        "pass" : "secret"
      },
      "sys2" : {
        "puid" : "sys2",
        "host" : "myhost",
        "syst" : "U",
        "user" : "yyyy",
        "pass" : "secret2"
      },
     "sys3" : {
        "puid" : "sys3",
        "host" : "localhost",
        "syst" : "U",
        "user" : "zzzz",
        "pass" : "secret3"
      },
    }
```

This is probably the right way to write it, but unfortunately, I can't control the format of the JSON files that I'm given. They are in the original format, shown higher up.

I've tried several things to no avail. I've tried several web searches but don't really know what to put into the search bar (hence this more detailed question).

At this moment in time I've put my code back to this simple line to be fixed with advice from SO :)

```
String json = new ObjectMapper( ).writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter( ).writeValueAsString( map );
```

---

**UPDATE**

Apologies for my vagueness last night, I was very tired.

However I now have a working solution based on the answer below from Michael. Use a List,  not a Map.

Amended and working code here if anyone ever should come across this issue (or for my own reference in the future)

```
  List<Object> jsonList = new ArrayList<Object>( map.values( ) );
  ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper( );
  String jsonOutput = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter( ).writeValueAsString( jsonList );
```

Comment: Map is a key value pair so the result is correct. Use a list or only the entry set of your map.

Comment: I've just left the office, read your comment and it makes perfect sense now. Spent too long looking at this today 

Comment: Further thinking on the way home.... I should not be working with the map but instead with a Collection or List of the Objects and discard the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Map always converts to JSON Object and not to JSON array. so your result is expected. If you want the original JSON format you should convert your data into `List<Map<String, Object>>` or `List<Map<String, String>>` and then you will get your original format

Comment: Thank you Michael. I will give this a go in the morning and post an update.

Comment: List<Map<>> should also get the label for each value.

Comment: For what its worth after this question getting closed - This was the answer that pointed me in the right direction and now I have my code working. It took 10 minutes this morning to get  it right. Working with a List instead of a Map was all I needed to know/remember. Thank you Michael.

Comment: @thonnor, Thank you so much for a very positive feedback. I appreciate very much. BTW, besides voting for the answer which anyone can do you as the OP (Original Poster)  can endorse it as the right answer. And for what it worth, I don't think the question should be closed. I think it is clear and relevant question

Comment: No worries. I forgot to accept the answer. I did mean to.